# removing duplicates by comparing substrings in a list

Tags: python, list, substring

I have a list `l = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']` . I want to get the following list without duplicated characters `new_l = ['AB','CA','AD']`. I am trying to iterate on a nested loop but I'm not sure this is the best way to accomplish this. here is my try:

```
new_l = []

for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(l)-1):
        if l[i][j] != l[i+1][j+1]:
            new_l = ..............
```

Can someone help me on how to get a set by iterating over every element of this list of strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set can mess order of characters. Better use OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
strl = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
result = ["".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)) for s in strl]
```

Comment: Note: In python3.7 or above the order of the keys is preserved in dictionaries.

Comment: @Zaven Zareyan could you explain your code since `.fromkeys` Create a new ordered dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value. I don't get how `.fromkeys` make a `set` of `strl`

Comment: You're joining by `""` character (i.e. by nothing) the keys of OrderedDict (`join` method goes only to keys) created from keys, (i.e. `{'key1': None, 'key2': None}`).

Comment: sorry still don't understand why joining by empty character will remove duplicates

Comment: OrderedDict makes your string like: `'AAB'-> {'A': None, 'B': None}` and removes duplicates. Then you're joining keys and get 'AB'

Comment: ok now I understood thanks. I tried the normal `dictionary` and it also works since the order is preserved in python 3.7 or above.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it, since a string is also a list.

```
strl = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
new_strl = []
for s in strl:
  new_strl.append("".join(set(s)))

print(new_strl)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA']
new_l = [''.join(sorted(set(x))) for x in l]
#op
['AB', 'AC', 'AD']
```